# Error in merge sort program

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, data-structures, merge

I am doing a merge sort program in C but I'm getting some unexpected output.
Can anyone find out error in the program?

```
   #include<stdio.h>

    int array[100],n;
    void merge(int l,int m,int h);
    void mergesort(int start,int end);
    main(){
    int i;
    printf("Enter Size: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        scanf("%d",&array[i]);      
    }
    mergesort(0, n-1);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("%d\n",array[i]);        
        }
    }

    void mergesort(int start,int end){
    int mid;
    if(start<end){
        mid=(start+end)/2;
        mergesort(start,mid);
        mergesort(mid+1,end);
        merge(start,mid,end);
        }
     }

    void merge(int start,int mid,int end){
    int i,j,k;
    int a1[100],a2[100];

    for(k=0,i=start;i<=mid;i++,k++){
        a1[k]=array[i];
    }
    for(k=0,j=i;j<=end;j++,k++){
        a2[k]=array[j]; 
    }
    a1[mid]=999;
    a2[j]=999;
    i=0;j=0;
    for(k=start; k <=end; k++)
    {
        if(a1[i]<=a2[j])
            array[k]=a1[i++];
        else
            array[k]=a2[j++];
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Enter Size: 5
1 2 3 2 3
2
2
3
3
-1818025592
```

For larger arrays, the output is more scrambled. I think there is an error in merge() function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are terminating your a1 and a2 arrays at the wrong location.

Try changing:

```
for(k=0,i=start;i<=mid;i++,k++){
    a1[k]=array[i];
}
for(k=0,j=i;j<=end;j++,k++){
    a2[k]=array[j]; 
}
a1[mid]=999;
a2[j]=999;
```

to

```
for(k=0,i=start;i<=mid;i++,k++){
    a1[k]=array[i];
}
a1[k]=999;
for(k=0,j=i;j<=end;j++,k++){
    a2[k]=array[j]; 
}
a2[k]=999;
```

Answer (score 1):

When you create your temporary arrays:

```
for (k = 0, i = start; i <= mid; i++, k++) {
    a1[k] = array[i];
}
a1[i] = 999;
```

you put a sentinel value with a high value at the end. But `i` is the index into the original `array`. You must use `k`, the index of the temporary array `a1`:

```
for (k = 0, i = start; i <= mid; i++, k++) {
    a1[k] = array[i];
}
a1[k] = 999;
```

Even so, the double control structure with `k` and `i` is clumsy. And  there's no need to guess a high number; `<limits.h>` has constants defined for the min and max values of most types:

```
k = 0;
for (i = start; i <= mid; i++) {
    a1[k++] = array[i];
}
a1[k] = INT_MAX;
```

Here, you increment `k` when an item is appended. This works even when the assignment happens conditionally, i.e. not in all iterations.

Finally, I would recommend to use exclusive upper bounds. That's the natural way to express ranges in C. `mid` would then be both the exclusive upper bound of the left array and the inclusive lower bound of the right array.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it 
a[mid + 1]=999 
a[k]=999